# How to set spinner item when opening layout in this case?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I use this library https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

When i click a button i will open a dialog layout that include `EditText` and `Spinner`.

My problem is i don't know how to set my `Spinner` item when the dialog layout open. This library make me declare my `Spinner` under `setOnClickListener`, because i have to use `dialog.getHolderView()` to get the view. I think it is the problem, but i don't know how to fix it.

In my code, i must click the `Spinner` then my spinner item will be added.

Here is my code:

```
public void openSearchLayout() {
    DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(getActivity())
            .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.search_layout))
            .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogPlus dialog, View view) {

                    EditText presenterEdit = (EditText) dialog.getHolderView().findViewById(R.id.presenterEdit);
                    final Spinner searchDate = (Spinner) dialog.getHolderView().findViewById(R.id.searchDate);
                    // Clear spinner data
                    dateList.clear();
                    // Set spinner item function
                    showRoute(myJson, searchDate);
                    switch (view.getId()) {
                        case R.id.searchDate:
                            searchDate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    // Clear spinner data
                                    arrayList.clear();
                                    // Search the spinner item value list
                                    showDateRoute(myJson, searchDate.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        case R.id.searchButton:
                            String testString = presenterEdit.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), testString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .setExpanded(true, 900)  // This will enable the expand feature, (similar to android L share dialog)
            .create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is my custom layout for dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signUpDate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/searchDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_arrow"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:theme="@style/mySpinnerStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/circlePresenter"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/presenterEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_edit"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_search"
        android:text="@string/integralDateSearch"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

According to Reaz reply i update like this:

```
ViewHolder dialogViewHolder = new ViewHolder(R.layout.search_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
final EditText presenterEdit = (EditText) dialogViewHolder.getView(inflater, null).findViewById(R.id.presenterEdit);
final Spinner searchDate = (Spinner) dialogViewHolder.getView(inflater, null).findViewById(R.id.searchDate);
// Clear spinner data
dateList.clear();
// Set spinner item function
showRoute(myJson, searchDate);

DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(getActivity())
        .setContentHolder(dialogViewHolder)
        //.....
```

Comment: Do you have static items in your spinner? Or you get the spinner items from via a server API call?

Comment: Yes, i get my spinner items from server API call. The data is fine, cuz i click the spinner from dialog layout , i can see the select item in spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following, getting the view out of the dialog initialization. Initialize the view first, populate the spinner and then pass it to the dialog in the constructor of your `ViewHolder`.

I have tested it. And it works in my device.

```
public void openSearchLayout() {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_layout, null);
    final EditText presenterEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.presenterEdit);
    final Spinner searchDate = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.searchDate);
    // Clear spinner data
    dateList.clear();
    // Set spinner item function
    showRoute(searchDate);

    DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(view))
            .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogPlus dialog, View view) {
                    switch (view.getId()) {
                        case R.id.searchDate:
                            searchDate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    // Clear spinner data
                                    //arrayList.clear();
                                    // Search the spinner item value list
                                    //showDateRoute(myJson, searchDate.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        case R.id.searchButton:
                            String testString = presenterEdit.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, testString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .setExpanded(true, 900)  // This will enable the expand feature, (similar to android L share dialog)
            .create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

I have populated the items in the spinner using the following function. Just had to add a sample `showRoute` function to check if the items are being populated correctly.

```
public void showRoute(Spinner spinner) {
    List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("item1");
    spinnerArray.add("item2");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try it , but it has a problem when declare `final EditText presenterEdit = (EditText) dialogViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.presenterEdit);` Cannot resolve method findViewById . It looks like i don't get the activity to find by id.

Comment: Sorry, you need to find the view first using the `getView` function. I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks again, but i find that `getView()` method must add some arguments, so i try `LayoutInflater` to set activity .  I update it in my question its still no working, there is no spinner item has been set :(

Comment: I get your problem now. The code is modified and updated. I have got it working in my side as well. Please let me know if you face any further issues.

Comment: Thank you so much @ReazMurshed, i don't event think that i don't need to use `dialogPlus.getHeaderView();` . The library document say about get view is `View view = dialogPlus.getHeaderView();`  after all.  Your answer is perfect and working.